# Extracting information that always follows a specific string

Tags: c#, string, file, search

I am trying to extract the information after a specific string int a file. Following is the segment that contains the string:

```
<Plane TheZ="0" TheT="0" TheC="0" DeltaT="0.2056"/><TiffData FirstT="0" FirstZ="0"
```

The information I am trying to extract is `0.2056` which always follows `DeltaT="`
I want this search to be as quick as possible. So I am wondering what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Are there tags with that attribute other than Plane?  If so, do you want the values from those attributes as well?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a regular expression

```
var regex = new Regex(@"DeltaT=""(.*?)""");
foreach (Match m in regex.Matches(inputText))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

However, since it looks like it ***might*** be X(HT)ML, prefer Linq-To-Xml if possible

Comment: "auto"? Are you mixing up your languages?

Comment: @ChristofferLette sorry, yeah that was C++ coming through ...:( thanks

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to build and app that reads XML.

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(myXmlFile);
Console.WriteLine(doc.SelectSingleNode("/@DeltaT").Value);
```

Here is a sample:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/myXPath.aspx

Comment: Roger, link only answers aren't good for SO. Please include _at least_ the essence of an example inside the post.